# WPF Style BasedOn not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why do my Radiobutton not look like a togglebutton?
Take a look at the code

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
<Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" />
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" />


<StackPanel>
    <Button>Button</Button>
    <ToggleButton>Toggle</ToggleButton>
    <RadioButton>Radio</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

If I remove the buttonbase style it works

Comment: What do you mean by "not look like a togglebutton"? What "works" after you remove the buttonbase style, but not before?

Answer (score 1):

The looks of your `RadioButton` is not as `ToggleButton` cause of you have now changed the style hierarchy of `ButtonBase->ToggleButton->RadioButton` (the order in which styles and templates are overwritten in derived classes of WPF).

Your new hierarchy of style gives the most priority to the style of `ButtonBase`. So you have a new `ToggleButton` style that is derived from a `ButtonBase` and then you overwrite the `RadioButton` style with that. So noone can tell you for sure which properties have you overwritten and which will be the final set of properties.

**To understand this change the `XAML` as following:**

```
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" />
```

and now see the look & feel of your `RadioButton`.

[image: preview]

I'm not clarifying what is exactly happened and why your `ToggleButton` is not affected so much. 
**But as I said it's all about the style hierarchy which is build for a control at last just before rendering on the UI.**

Comment: I miss red the question, i was/Am in a hurry, you have an answer that suits better the question, i will take a deeper look when i get home, +1

Comment: @SamTheDev No Prob. I'm sure you will provide better explanation, as I haven't provided a very clear definitive answer.